# Nesting string.splits in a for loop - inner split gets NPE when assigned

Tags: java, android, arrays, split, iterator

So, today I hit a snag trying to split a string array element which has been split from a long string already.. It works like this:
A string is created from a file. This string is split at blank lines (\n\n) which are basically paragraphs of text, which gets used as body text elsewhere.
Each paragraph begins with a topic, followed by an asterisk, followed by the body text. 
Here's the issue - 
It would be too simple to, while iterating through each paragraph string element to split these at the asterisk character (escaped, of course). To demonstrate, the first part works well:

```
sections = formatted.split("\n\n");  //sections previously declared as string array
int lines = sections.length ;
for(int i= 0 ; i< lines; i++) {
    sections[i] = "Heading\n\n" + sections[i] ;
```

Now, when trying to perform another task in each iteration (yes, just join the two code windows together in your mind), it throws NPE on the second resulting index:

```
    String paragraph = sections[i];
    String[] half = paragraph.split("\\*");
    topics[i] = half[0];    //Topics also previously declared as array
}
```

The last line inside the iterator throws a NPE (not out of bounds). I can't tell if it's the I or the ) index.

I would really appreciate understanding why this doesn't work. Perhaps it's because I always seem to hit these problems well after midnight...

How can I build these two parallel instance arrays?  Thanks!

Comment: Please take more care when formatting code in future - it's *much* easier to read if we don't need to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that if I didn't see a scrollbar on my screen, that it would be ok. oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems likely to me that `Topics` is null - there's nothing within the code you've shown to assign it a non-null value. You probably want:

```
Topics = new String[lines];
```

before the loop. You should be able to spot this pretty easily in the debugger, too. (If you're confused about where an NPE is coming from, adding diagnostics and/or debugging are usually the first steps.)

Also note that conventionally your variables would be called `sections` and `topics`, as variables in Java are usually camelCased.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try as soon as I fix my variable names...Note to self: when messing up naming conventions, drink more coffee, or simple logic will get messed up also!

Comment: Thanks Jon, that was it. declaring a class variable for the array was not sufficient. Excellent catch.